# 'Pay as you go' and 'container hour' subscriptions

Tags: meteor, payment, subscription

I was trying to create a Meteor Galaxy subscription and the price model says it's a Pay as you go and starts at $0.035 / container hour. What's that mean?

If I didn't use the service will I be charged? (Thinking pay as you go won't be). I'm not sure though.

And what's container hour rate? I will be using the Galaxy for small apps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about a programming issue but about an external service payment plan.

Comment: This is, of course, not a programming question.  But it is of interest to programmers, so a bit of help on where it should be asked would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:
https://www.meteor.com/why-meteor/galaxy-faq

Based on the example they have given, if you run it continuously it can amount to ~$25/month. (assuming 30 days a month , 24 * 30 * $0.035/hr = $25.2/month).

Container hour is the time your application is running on their container. If you want to stop getting charged , I believe you need to stop the app from running.